# If I'm "dictating" am I recording what you say or telling you what to do?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, word-usage

In a document that I'm writing, I am trying to state that, in the course of conducting a user interview, I am **"not simply *dictating* the desires of the user."**  My intention is to indicate that I am not simply *recording* the desires of the user, but when reading the sentence aloud it sounds like I am not simply *prescribing* the desires of the user.  Both definitions seem to be correct, according to the dictionary.

- Does the connotation of *dictate* lean more to one definition over the other?
- Is there a better word to describe my intent?

(This is my first English.SE question, so please tell me if there is a better way for me to ask a question.)

Comment: I'm curious why this is being considered off-topic.  The first listed acceptable topic is "Word choice and usage".  Would this question have been better if I had copied a dictionary definition as "research"?  Based on the comments below, it should be clear that I did not understand how the use of the word "dictating" changed when modified with "take".  Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you **dictate** something, you can be either:

> - Telling somebody what they must do or agree to. (For instance, the victorious side in a military conflict can **dictate surrender terms** to the losing side.)
> - Reading out a text for somebody else to write down (= transcribe, record in writing)

When you **take dictation,** you are transcribing/recording in writing what another person is reading out.

**Dictation exercises** are sometimes used as a way to test the comprehension of language learners.

Comment: How would that be phrased in this context then: "I am not simply taking dictation of the desires of the user."?  That seems a little odd; but since I clearly don't say "take dictation" often I may just be uncomfortable with this construction.

Comment: I can't think of a way in which you can use the verb *dictate* (or any of its derivatives) to express this idea that would not sound peculiar.  Instead, you would have to say something like "I am not simply recording the desires of the user", in line with the wording of the explanation you gave in your original question.

Comment: @ErikKowal Let's say I am a news correspondent seeking the views of an official. There is a dual need to report accurately what the person says, and to put it into a context which neutralises any political spin that the official may be putting on the matter. Emphasising the importance of the second I might argue that *it is not just a task of taking dictation*. That would seem to me normal idiomatically correct language.

Comment: @WS2 - In that kind of situation, that would indeed be an appropriate way to describe it.

Answer (score 0):

To dictate (verb) is always to produce speech, not to record it.

Maybe you looked up the noun *dictation*, which might have led to confusion because it is used to describe both the production and (usually with *take*) the recording aspects.

*I am not simply (or only or merely) recording users' desires (or responses)* may be a good way to express what you want to say. We would probably need more information to make a better suggestion.

Comment: That's really helpful about the verb.  More information: user interviews have been conducted to synthesize product use cases, all were verbal conversations (not emails or the like).  In summarizing, I am trying to get across the point that I did not simply copy down a user's desire to form a use case, but instead put in some thought to construct a use case out of the user's responses during the interview.

Comment: You can use *transcribe* as appears in Erik's answer. You did not merely transcribe, you interpreted and synthesized, perhaps.

Comment: _Transcribe_ seems to make the most sense.  Thank you both.

Comment: Or "repeating" would work as well.

Comment: Yes, @Brian. *Repeating* is stronger and simpler.